# Excel media image name not match

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, xlsx

Background:
I was trying to extract the image from PDF File, but I fail to do so,
I then convert the PDF file to .xlsx file, because I know I can just unzip the xlsx.

Question:
But I found out that the image name does not match the name in the media file in xl file.
For example when I click the image in excel, it shows image135.png, but the image135.png in media file is different, in media file the image should be image134.png
Looks like at some point the image number just went wrong but I don't know why.

Reason:
The reason I need the name to be correct is because I am trying to rename the image with the value which is in the same cell as the image. So I use VBA to get the text I need and the image name in the same cells so I may just replace the name (I have not found a way to save image out through VBA).

Comment: It is always the same pattern? What happens with the first and last images?

Comment: The first 214 image is correct, until 215.png , the 216.png become 215.png and I don't think 215.png exist in the excel file